# setting function prototype in Lua

Tags: function, lua, coronasdk

A simple question: How do I set the prototype for a function that has not been implemented yet?

I just want to do this, cause I'm referring to a function that does not exist(yet).
In C, we would do something like this:

```
int foo(int bar);

int myint = foo(1);

int foo(int bar)
{
     return bar;
}
```

How do I do this in Lua (with corona)?

Comment: You don't. Lua is a dynamically-interpreted, line-by-line evaluated language; thus trying to invoke a function before it actually has a body isn't valid.

Comment: just like this? What do I have to do in that case then? Put all post-used functions in the beginning of the file? I don't think that rearrange the file everytime a function comes in is a valid way. And there'll be situations that I won't work anyway. Do you have a clue?

Comment: In general, you should have almost zero code at the top level - instead of putting your calls to functions at the top level, put them inside a `main()` function or similar, and only invoke your `main()` function at the end of the file. That way, all of the other functions will be defined by the time `main()` funs.

Comment: As an extra note; languages that allow this behaviour (named hoisting) end up with all sorts of difficulties :)

Comment: well, since difficulties is something we can pass by, I'm in! thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't. Amber's comment is correct.

Lua doesn't have a concept of type signatures or function prototypes.

The type of `foo` is that of the object it contains, which is dynamic, changing at runtime. It could be `function` in one instant, and `string` or `integer` or something else in the next.

*Conceptually* Lua doesn't have a compilation step like C. When you say "run this code" it starts starts executing instructions at the top and works it's way down. In *practice*, Lua first compiles your code into bytecode before executing it, but the compiler won't balk at something like this:

```
greet()

function greet()
    print('Hello.')
end
```

Because the value contained in `greet` is determined at runtime. It's only when you actually try to *call* (i.e. invoke like a function) the value in `greet`, at runtime, that Lua will discover that it doesn't contain a callable value (a function or a table/userdata with a metatable containing a `__call` member) and you'll get a runtime error: "attempt to call global 'greet' (a nil value)". Where "nil value" is whatever value `greet` contained at the time the call was attempted. In our case, it was `nil`.

So you will have to make sure that that the code that creates a function and assigns it to `foo` is called before you attempt to call `foo`.

---

It might help if you recognize that this:

```
local myint = foo(1)

function foo(bar)
     return bar
end
```

Is syntax sugar for this:

```
local myint = foo(1)

foo = function(bar)
     return bar
end
```

`foo` is being assigned a function value. That has to happen before you attempt to call that function.

---

The most common solution to this problem is to treat the file's function as the "compilation time", that is: declare all of your constant data and functions when the file is executed, ready to be used during "execution time". Then, call a `main` function to begin the "execution time".

For example:

```
function main()
    greet()
end

function greet()
    print('Hello.')
end

main()
```

As `greet` has been declared in `_G`, `main` can access it.

Comment: Migrating from C to Lua may be complicated these times. Thanks for your helpful post, both Amber and Mud.